# Flutter : How to show data HTML result from response API?

Tags: flutter, dart, html-dataset

Hello everybody I has a response data in HTML format and I want to manage the data to display in screen. I use library `flutter_html`.

**This is my code**

```
Future<String> getHtml() async {
var headers = {
  'Cookie': 'ci_session=hgiugh'
};
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('http://xxx/get'));
request.fields.addAll({
  '': '',
});

request.headers.addAll(headers);

final http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print("HTML_RESULT"+await response.stream.bytesToString());
}
else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}

return await response.stream.bytesToString();}
```

I've the HTML but I got `instance of 'Future'` when i want to show it.

Code for show the data

```
var i;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    i = getHtml();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Html(
            data: i.toString(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Please give me a help guys, any reference is important to me, thank you.

Comment: you either await your response or use the "then" method. You need to wait for that internet server response, if not, is not going to work. Once you get the content, then you need to update the state of your build.

Comment: thanks @MarianoZorrilla, could you give me some of code you mean ?,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the

```
final http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
```

for:

```
http.Response response = await http.Response.fromStream(await request.send());
```

You have to await the getHtml() too, but you can't do it directly on init.

```
void loadResponse() async {
    final response = await getHtml();
    setState(() {
        i = response;
    });
}
```

And then call the method on init():

```
@override
void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
  loadResponse();
}
```

Comment: thanks @João Pedro Martins, but if I change I hasn't the data response

Comment: I've edited the answer, try now.

Comment: still hasn't data and I got "Instance of 'Response'"

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the `if (response.statusCode == 200)`can you see the data when debug stops?

Comment: @Mas'udAlHafiz, when you change the `final http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();` for `http.Response response = await http.Response.fromStream(await request.send());`, you have to change the return of `getHtml()` too, to either `response.body` or `response.bodyBytes`. Otherwise you will get 'Instance of Response'.

Comment: thanks for your help, thats work and I'll do next my job, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Extract this line into seperated code

```
print("HTML_RESULT"+await response.stream.bytesToString());
```

like

```
var responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();
print("HTML_RESULT $responseString");
```

**EDIT:**

As of @Mariano said, you need to create new function

```
void load() async {
    ... do your await here
    ... and after you got the value call
    setState(() {
        ... set your value here
    });
}
```

and call that function from initState

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    load();
  }
```

Comment: I've the data, but now I want to show it on screen and has instance of 'Future' @cahyo

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (responseString == null ||
        responseString.contains("A PHP Error was encountered") ||
        responseString.contains("<div") ||
        responseString.contains("</html")) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Server Error",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0);

    }
```